# function.apply( argument1, array) not taking all values from array

Tags: javascript

`function.apply` does not register the first argument (index 0) in my array.

I have tried the rest/spread syntax, and 
the code below seems to work fine:

```
let sayName = function (object, ...languages) {
    console.log(`My name is ${this.name} and I speak ${languages.join(', ')}`);
};

let stacy = {
    name: 'Stacy',
    age: 34
};

let languages = ['Javascript', 'CSS', 'German','English', 'Spanish'];
sayName(stacy, ...languages);
```

But the code below does not work, with explicit binding `function.apply`:

```
let languages1 = ['Javascript', 'CSS', 'German','English', 'Spanish'];
sayName.apply(stacy, languages1)
```

The result always leaves out the 0 index from the array, i.e. "Javascript" is not included in the output.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first argument you pass to `apply` is used as the `this` object assignment. It is not passed as argument to your function. All that is in the documentation of [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Syntax). Since you reference `this` in your function, just *remove* the `object` parameter from your function header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function seems to expect an `object` parameter, but that is incorrect seeing how you call it with `apply`. When you call `apply` or `call`, the first argument to that method is used to set the `this` value for your function's execution context. It does not get passed as argument.

As your function references `this`, it is important that you set `this` correctly, and so the use of `apply` or `call` is the good choice.

So change:

```
let sayName = function (object, ...languages) {
```

to:

```
let sayName = function (...languages) {
```

Note that you didn't use `object` anyway in your function's code.

In the version where you don't call `apply`, but call the function directly, you do:

```
sayName(stacy, ...languages);
```

...but here the `this` object will not be set correctly. You should have used `call` to ensure that `this` will refer to `stacy`:

```
sayName.call(stacy, ...languages);
```

Check out the documentation of [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Syntax):

> ## Syntax
>
> ```
> function.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])
> ```
>
> #### Parameters
>
> **thisArg**
>
> Optional. The value of `this` provided for the call to *func*. [...]
>
> **argsArray**
>
> Optional. An array-like object, specifying the arguments with which *func* should be called. [...]

## Object oriented programming, a better way

Now, taking a step back you should really have defined `sayName` as a prototype method, and construct `stacy` like so:

```js
class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    sayName(...languages) {
        console.log(`My name is ${this.name} and I speak ${languages.join(', ')}`);
    }
}

let stacy = new Person('Stacy', 34);
let languages = ['Javascript', 'CSS', 'German','English', 'Spanish'];
stacy.sayName(...languages);
```

... and why not actually store the languages a person speaks as a property as well, and remove the `console.log` from the method, as it should be the caller who decides to where the output should be made (maybe to a file or to a HTML element):

```js
class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.languages = [];
    }
    speaks(...languages) {
        this.languages = languages;
    }
    introduction() {
        return `My name is ${this.name} and I speak ${this.languages.join(', ')}`;
    }
}

let stacy = new Person('Stacy', 34);
stacy.speaks('Javascript', 'CSS', 'German','English', 'Spanish');
console.log(stacy.introduction());
```

Comment: A great example for me to delve into and look at the documentation more. Thanks alot